Modelling presence/absence data with PC scores
I have some data of animal counts vs. PCA scores of environmental variables that looks as below. The .5s in the count data are because two people counted and we took an average.
  data <- data.frame(
  pc1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 2.7, 0.9, 1.1, 0.3, 1.5, 1.7, 2.9),
  pc2 = c(3.1, 1.3, 2.7, 2.7, 2.1, 1.3, 2.3, 3.5, 1.7, 3.9),
  count = c(0,1.5, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0)
)

I want to test whether the PC scores (environmental variables) have an effect on the counts.
I was using:
lm.count <- lm(count ~ pc1 + pc2, data)
summary (lm.count)

Output:
Call:
lm(formula = count ~ pc1 + pc2, data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3547 -0.3614 -0.2009  0.5609  1.8412 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.300000   0.241209   5.390 0.000163 ***
pc1          0.004687   0.158655   0.030 0.976920    
pc2         -0.118962   0.170177  -0.699 0.497848    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9342 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0392,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1209 
F-statistic: 0.2448 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.7867

But I am wondering whether the large number of zero-count information will skew the data and mean that using this model is incorrect. Chat GTP suggested I try using a logistic model for presence and absence:
logistic_model <- glm(count > 0 ~ pc1 + pc2, family = binomial, data = data)
summary(logistic_model)

Output:
Call:
glm(formula = count > 0 ~ pc1 + pc2, family = binomial, data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2854   0.3479   0.5064   0.5594   0.7567  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  1.98844    0.83717   2.375   0.0175 *
pc1          0.37118    0.52065   0.713   0.4759  
pc2          0.05496    0.52303   0.105   0.9163  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.780  on 14  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 11.239  on 12  degrees of freedom
AIC: 17.239

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

Is this better? The model summary comes out wholly insignificant but when plotting the model predictions against the PC1 axis it's an almost perfect correlation. So I'm sure something has gone wrong..
This was the code (real data figure at the end):
predicted_probs <- predict(logistic_model, type = "response")
data$predicted_probs <- predicted_probs

plot(data$pc1, data$predicted_probs,
     xlab = "pc1", ylab = "Predicted Probability of counts > 0",
     main = "Logistic Regression: Predicted Probability vs PC1",
     pch = 19, col = "blue")

I feel like the mismatch between the model significance and the plotted predictions indicates something's gone wrong. Perhaps the model is correct and the plot is wrong? Or the other way round. But if there was no correlation I was expecting the points in the plot to be all over the place.
And this is the plot:


You have a couple of things going on:

Your data set is on the small side, but that's not a huge deal, just a note on the power being low for your tests
Since you're averaging the counts, and they're no longer integers, an ordinary regression isn't wrong, but see the end of my answer.
Changing from linear to logistic changes things a bit. In logistic, you're now trying to predict the log probability of a non-zero count, rather than the actual numerical value of the count variable
Since PC1 was a variable in your model, you would want it to correlate with your predicted probabilities, but you can see that across the range of PC1, there isn't a huge change in the probability of a non-zero count. Again, here I think we're back to the size of the dataset.

One thing you might also do, though it wouldn't necessarily solve your sample size issue, is to go back to the two people who did the counting and see if they can come to consensus on the counts, so you can set them back to integers. Then you could fit a count-regression with log link (aka, "Poisson regression"), which will model the log of the expected counts, and save information that's discarded in the logistic model.
Here's an illustration of the Poisson results on your $n = 10$ dataset by rounding the decimals. Whether this is warranted is up to you:
poisson_model <- glm(count_int ~ pc1 + pc2, family = poisson, data = data)
summary(poisson_model)

Call:
glm(formula = count_int ~ pc1 + pc2, family = poisson, data = data)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.9148     1.3868   0.660    0.509
pc1          -0.5110     0.6752  -0.757    0.449
pc2          -0.4988     0.6140  -0.812    0.417

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 12.477  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10.658  on 7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 23.886

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

> cbind(exp(coef(poisson_model)), exp(confint(poisson_model)))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                          2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 2.4963032 0.1368765 36.428825
pc1         0.5998701 0.1163095  1.999953
pc2         0.6072631 0.1582417  1.970419

Nothing here says to reject the null hypothesis for either predictor. The exponentiated coefficients are "rate ratios", i.e., the $0.59987$ for pc1 means as pc1 increases, counts / rate of animals have a tendency to change by a factor of about $0.60$ or by ~ $(0.60 - 1.0) \times 100\%$ meaning a drop in the count / rate of about $40\%$. However, the CI contains $1.0$ which is the value of the point-null, which would correspond to a raw coefficient of $0$. So again, with $\alpha = .05$ the null hypothesis would not be rejected.

Thank you! I should have made it clearer but the dataframe used above is a sample dataframe and not the full set - although the full set is still small (n=15). The counts were field measures so may be hard to agree post-hoc, but I suppose rounding up could be an option? Poisson would be ideal in this case - I'll have a look at that.
Regarding the code above, is there anything that's objectively wrong in the logistic model, perhaps beyond a loss of data?

Nope, nothing wrong, except I usually make a separate 0 / 1 binary variable rather than doing the count > 0 the formula. But it does the same thing. One thing to note, with your data, I did look at the scatterplots relating the counts to the pcs's and the relationship doesn't look very linear. I also ran a Poisson model and the results are in the correct direction, p-values are quite high. I've updated my answer to include that.
